# Symfony error targeted by Callback constraint is not a valid callable

Tags: validation, symfony

I have this error. Help please.

I use this instruction http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html for 3.0 version (i use Symfony 3.0)

My validation.yml

```
App\Bundle\NameBundle\Entity\Product:
    constraints:
        - Callback: [validate]
```

Entity

```
namespace App\Bundle\NameBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
/**
 * Product
 */
class Product
{
    /**
    * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /* ... some code .... */

     public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
     {
         $context->buildViolation('This name sounds totally fake!')
             ->atPath('firstName')
             ->addViolation();
     }
}
```

**what am I doing wrong?**

**SOLUTION:**

in validation.yml

```
...
- Callback: validate
...
```

Comment: Where is the actual error?  What is going wrong?  Where are you trying to apply this?  etc.

Comment: i found solution, thank you

Answer (score 5):

Error in string 3 validation.yml

```
    - Callback: [validate] #wrong
    - Callback: validate #right
```

Comment: This was the solution for me. Thanks!