# Symfony erron on callback constraint validation

Tags: php, symfony, validation, callback

I am attempting to apply this
[symfony callback constraint reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html), but I am getting the following error:

> [] targeted by Callback constraint is not a valid callable

I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158556/symfony-error-targeted-by-callback-constraint-is-not-a-valid-callable), which did not help much.

So, what I am trying to do is to limit input to a entity field to a defined array of items ( self::$valid_years in the code below ).

I also did a dump on the variable $method on class below, which generates the error, and in fact the $method variable is an empty array.

> Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\CallbackValidaor.php

This is the entity:

Warranty.php

```php
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\WarrantyRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="warranties")
*/
class Warranty
{
    /** 
    * @ORM\Id 
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Brand") 
    * @Assert\NotBlank(message="La marque est requise.")
    */
    private $brand;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=5)
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    private $wrYear;

    .... some code .....

    public static $valid_years;
    public static $valid_wrpaint;
    public static $valid_wrcorr;
    public static $valid_wrtransf;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$valid_years = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','ilim');
        self::$valid_wrpaint = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','ilim','n/c');
        self::$valid_wrcorr = array('0','3','7','8','12','13','ilim','n/c');
        self::$valid_wrtransf = array('Y','N','n/c');
    }



    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
    {
                \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump(self::$valid_years);
        if (!in_array($this->getWrYear(), self::$valid_years)) {
            $context->buildViolation('Invalid year!')
                ->atPath('wrYear')
                ->addViolation();
        }

    }

    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addConstraint(new Assert\Callback('validate'));
    }

    .... some code....
    /**
     * Get wrYear
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWrYear()
    {
        return $this->wrYear;
    }
}
```

validation.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Warranty:
    constraints:
        - Callback: validate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration for validation seems mixed up. Use below for annotation configuration

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\WarrantyRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="warranties")
 */
class Warranty
{
        /**
         * @Assert\Callback
         */
        public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
        {
            // ...
        }
}
```

Then remove your validation.yml config (yml configuration) and loadValidatorMetadata (PHP configuration)

Comment: well done @Asha. Additional kudos for persistence. That works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Callback Validator can by call `statically` by Symfony so may be it's why your array is empty.

Can you try to initialize your static properties outside the `__construct` method like this :

```
public static $valid_years = array(
    '0',
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    'ilim'
);
```

It will also be cleaner : if your static properties values are always the same, why wait to instantiate an object to initialize them ?

Comment: Thanks @Fabien Salles. Initializing the variable in the construct is just a beginner's mistake. I am new to Symfony and oop in general. I changed as you indicated, but it is still producing the same error.

Comment: You don't redefine you static property in an other place ?

Comment: Your `Assert\Callback`  annotation must be define for your `validate` method not for your `$wrYear` property